# Kendo UI MVC Grid in batch update display confirmation dialog on cancel changes

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid set to update the database in batch update mode with InCell editing. Everything works as it should. When the user clicks on the 'Cancel changes' button the cancelChanges method is called and the current changes are discarded (as they should).

I would like to display a confirmation dialog before actually discarding the changes. I want to prevent an accidental click on this button from cancelling all changes.

I looked at the DateSource object but I did not see any event I can handle to achieve this.

Does anyone have an idea on how to handle this situation?

Your help is most appreciated.
Daniel.

Answer (score -1):

Daniel,

IIRC, kendo grid uses a class 'k-grid-cancel' for its grid updates. If you wish to offer the user a confirmation, you may need to include a jquery event for the kendo cancel button:

```
$(".k-grid-cancel").click(function(e) { return confirm('Are you sure?'); });
```

I hope this helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Hi kryptonkal, Thank you for your answer. I tried that, but at the time the alert is shown, the changes are already canelled. Looks like that there is an event that fires before the button's click event that calls the cancelChanges method. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a e.preventdefault or return false. If you cancel the event, you may have to implement your own update method using jquery and then rebind the grid.

Comment: Thank you kryptonkal. Canceling the event may work. I will give it a try. Thanks for you help.